# how to limit one connection/user with oAuth2/spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am currently building a video/chat application.
Server side is spring-based, with spring security and oAuth2 about security concerns.
Front end is a Java FX8 application.

I want to limit my service to **one connection per user**.

I don't see any support of that in SpringSecurity/oAuth2.

What is the best solution to do that ?

Any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question in correct manner, you need this 
[Spring Security 3 Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html) and [Spring Security 4 Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions)

"Concurrency Controll"

Comment: Any idea how to do this in PHP+Apache?

Comment: I'm not experienced with PHP + Apache, but maybe looking through Spring's implementation for ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy class may help you.